# cannot use a local proxy on iOS 6 with Opera Mini

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, proxy, opera-mini

I am aware that Opera Mini uses a proxy to process the content, rather than processing the content on the device itself. Sadly, I believe this is causing me an issue when developing my mobile website for this browser.

I have a local proxy configured to point to my dev machine that allows me to access my code residing on my local machine. This is great and works well on Safari and Chrome, however I get a "Page Not Found" error on Opera Mini.

[image]
Is there any way to use a local proxy configured in iOS with Opera Mini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera Mini can only access servers that have a public IP. One option is to place your content on a password protected site.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-5-developers/#serverbased

Comment: Thanks, I was aware that OM is a Proxy Browser - but this makes it _really_ difficult to develop websites that are supported by OM. They really need to look at changing that in later versions. Not good.